# Faster way to put large nested xml into R dataframe

Tags: r, xml, dataframe, performance

I have a XML file that has nesting that is different from other examples I have seen. Here's the format it takes. I am interested in the data in the np nodes, but I also want the group and ID info in each row.

I have a working solution below, but the actual file is very large with thousands of  nodes. The solution takes hours and hours to run on the large file, although it works on the sample code below.

My question is - is there a faster way to get the dataframe I want?

```
<File>
  <Time>
    <date>20220301</date>
    <Name>1</Name>
<folder>
      <group>800</group>
      <ID>ESK</ID>
      <Type>S</Type>
      <Customer>1</Customer>
      <currency>USD</currency>
      <Port>
        <ec>X</ec>
        <np>
          <A>FIRST</A>
          <B>ES</B>
          <C>GOR</C>
          <D>2021</D>
          <E>-1000</E>
        </np>
        <np>
          <A>TEST</A>
          <B>ES</B>
          <C>RUN</C>
          <D>202303</D>
          <E>202303</E>
          <F>C</F>
          <G>3200</G>
          <H>32</H>
        </np>
      </Port>
</folder>
<folder>
      <group>900</group>
      <ID>ABC</ID>
      <Type>D</Type>
      <Customer>1</Customer>
      <currency>USD</currency>
      <Port>
        <ec>X</ec>
        <np>
          <A>CAT</A>
          <B>ES</B>
          <C>GO</C>
          <D>202303</D>
          <E>-500</E>
        </np>
       </Port>
</folder>
</Time>
</File>
```

Here is my current working solution. This works on small xml files, but for large files with that xml format it is too slow and takes hours to run.

```
URL <- 'H:/testSO.xml'
doc <- read_xml(URL)

df <-
  xml_find_all(doc, ".//np") %>%
  map_df( function(x) {
    set_names( c(  
      xml_find_all( x, "./ancestor::folder/group") %>% xml_text(),
      xml_find_all( x, "./ancestor::folder/ID") %>% xml_text(),
      xml_find_all( x, ".//A") %>% xml_text(),
      xml_find_all( x, ".//B") %>% xml_text(),
      xml_find_all( x, ".//C") %>% xml_text(),
      xml_find_all( x, ".//D") %>% xml_text(),
      xml_find_all( x, ".//E") %>% xml_text()), 
      #set the column names
      c( "group","id", "A", "B", "C","D","E") ) %>% 
      as.list() %>% #make list
      flatten_df() 
  }) %>%
  type_convert() 

head(df)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of the vectorization of the *xml2* library and avoid the `map_df` loop, this should provide a significant improvement in speed.

This routine finds all of the np nodes, extracts the requested information into a series of vectors, and then creates a data frame with the results.

```
library(xml2)
library(dplyr)
npnodes <- xml_find_all(doc, ".//np") 
   
group <- npnodes %>% xml_find_first( "./ancestor::folder/group") %>% xml_text()
id <- npnodes %>% xml_find_first("./ancestor::folder/ID") %>% xml_text()
A <- npnodes %>% xml_find_first(".//A") %>% xml_text()
B <- npnodes %>% xml_find_first(".//B") %>% xml_text()
C <- npnodes %>% xml_find_first(".//C") %>% xml_text()
D <- npnodes %>% xml_find_first(".//D") %>% xml_text()
E <- npnodes %>% xml_find_first(".//E") %>% xml_text() 

answer <- data.frame(group,id, A, B, C, D, E)
answer

  group  id     A  B   C      D      E
1   800 ESK FIRST ES GOR   2021  -1000
2   800 ESK  TEST ES RUN 202303 202303
3   900 ABC   CAT ES  GO 202303   -500
```

Comment: great solution. you are right, this handles the entire file in about a minute. thank you